# Why does String.intern() return different results under JDK 8 and JDK 9?

Tags: java, string-interning

The following codes has different results when run using JDK 8 and JDK 9.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s = new String("1");
    s.intern();
    String s2 = "1";
    System.out.println(s == s2);

    String s3 = new String("1") + new String("1");
    //String s3 = "1" + "1";
    s3.intern();
    String s4 = "11";
    System.out.println(s3 == s4);
    System.out.println(s3.equals(s4));
}
```

under JDK 8 (version 1.8.0_172), the codes prints:

```
false
true
true
```

but using JDK 9 (version 9.0.1),the codes returns:

```
false
false
true
```

I have checked two JDK versions and they are correct. Why does the code produce different results? Is there anything wrong with my program?

Comment: I checked in java-12, it shows output same as of Java-8.

Comment: When you say `s3.intern()`, do you actually mean `s3 = s3.intern()`?

Comment: Why do you care? You should normally not use `intern()` nor `new String(String)` in your code at all. While academically 'interesting', it serves no practical purpose for most ways of using Java.

Answer (score 8):

The result depends on whether the String "11" was already in the String pool prior to the call to `s3.intern()`.

If it wasn't, `s3.intern()` will add `s3` to the pool and return `s3`. In that case `s4` will also be assigned the canonical representation of "11", since it was initialized with a String literal. Therefore `s3==s4` would be `true`.

If it was, `s3.intern()` will return the canonical representation of "11", which is not the same instance as `s3`. Therefore `s3==s4` would be `false`.

I don't have a JDK9 version to test your code on, but if that's the output you got, it implies that somewhere in the JDK9 source code that gets executed before your `main`, there appears the "11" `String` literal, which adds that `String` to the pool.

This is not the case in JDK8.

Your test with the "1" `String` gives `false` in both cases, since the `String` "1" is added to the pool when you pass it to the `String` constructor in `new String("1")`. Therefore `s.intern()` doesn't add the `String` referenced by `s` to the pool, and `String s2 = "1";` is a difference instance than `s`.

The Javadoc of `intern` is handy when trying to understand this behavior:

> **String java.lang.String.intern()**
>
> Returns a canonical representation for the string object.
>
> A pool of strings, initially empty, is maintained privately by the class String.
>
> When the intern method is invoked, **if the pool already contains a string equal to this String object as determined by the equals(Object) method, then the string from the pool is returned. Otherwise, this String object is added to the pool and a reference to this String object is returned.**
>
> ...
>
> **All literal strings and string-valued constant expressions are interned.**

Comment: Good guess. Tested in Java 9 - when changing the string to absolute gibberish rather than "11", the result goes back to false-true-true. "11" must already be in the string pool.

Comment: @JBNizet if `s3.intern()` return `s3` (which means "11" wasn't in the pool prior to that call), then String s4 = "11" also returns `s3` (since a String literal doesn't create a new instance if an equal String is already in the pool). If "11" was already in the pool, `s3.intern()` will return an instance different than s3 (which would be the same instance as `s4`). Therefore we'll have `s3 != s4`

Comment: The culprit is the field `private static final java.lang.String VERSION_BUILD = "11";` in `java.lang.VersionProps`. Which applies to the JDK 9.0.1 named in the question, as its full version is `9.0.1+11` and also to the version `9.0.4+11`.